# Making Brick Walls/Stone Walls/Shingles Using Arrays and Particle Systems

Tags: modifiers

My goal is to make brick and stone walls, and shingle roofs utilizing a small collection of units spread over a plane using the array and particle systems.  I think I have figured out most of it from these two posts:

[Array with random objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183754/array-with-random-objects)

[Convert Particle System to Mesh (Collection NOT Object)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161294/convert-particle-system-to-mesh-collection-not-object)

So I can create an array that I can cut holes in.

Issues I can't figure out:

- I can't get the plane to fill completely with non-uniform units.  I started with Stones, and have 1x1, 1.5x1 and 2x1 stones that I want to fill a plane with, and there will be gaps, or lots of overlap if I increase the number of emitters.
- Unless I set the source as jittered and 1 particle per face, the seem to just appear everywhere randomly.

Is there a way to get a plane to fill with non-uniform shapes with no overlap and no gaps? Or more precisely, is there a way to create a semi-uniform stone wall with random stones of different lengths but uniform heights?

This is what I am trying to create, random length stones that are a uniform height:
[image: Wall]

Thank you for the suggestions, I will look up Geometry and Sverchok nodes.  Also, the end goal is to produce an .STL file for 3D printing.

Comment: you should think about using geometry nodes instead of arrays and particles....

Comment: and please add a screenshot what your "end goal" is, so that we can clearly see what you want

Comment: ok, maybe animation nodes is the right tool to do this...I think geonodes is until now not capable of doing this...

Comment: Hello ! I would definitely not advise using Blender Particles System for this task, it's not flexible enough. Geometry nodes are coming closer, but until we can script complex algorithms, it will be a real burden to do so. Animation Nodes or Sverchok can achieve this for instance, but they require a fair amount of time investment to master